# How can I generate a QR code for multiple outputs?

Tags: address

I have an online store where users can pay with Bitcoin. I'd like them to send the total amount they have to pay to an QR code. From there on, the sent coins should be redistributed to two different wallet addresses in a 90%:10% ratio. How can I possibly do this?

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! It would be a worthwhile project if you have the capability to do so, to define an extension to BIP 21 allowing distribution of payment from the wallet to multiple addresses.

Answer (score 1):

[BIP0021](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0021.mediawiki) (the contents of a QR code) does not specify a method for defining multiple addresses.

Comment: OK, are there any other options I can use besides QR codes?

Comment: No, everything uses BIP0021 at the base layer. You'd have to define a new standard extension and convince wallet authors to implement it.